# Interaction between Teferi Time Raveler and Enduring Ideal

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Teferi, Time Raveler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Time%20Raveler%5d)'s static ability, which limits opponents' spells to sorcery 'speed', stop [Enduring Ideal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnduring%20Ideal%5d)'s Epic ability which functions during the upkeep?

Comment: When MTG uses a rule-defined keyword (e.g. `cast`), it only refers to that specific keyword and no other. `copy` is not `cast`.

Answer (score 14):

No, it doesn't stop it. Teferi says:

> Each opponent can **cast** spells only any time they could cast a sorcery.

(emphasis mine)

But **copying** a spell is different from **casting** it:

> 706.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated.

Therefore, Teferi doesn't affect the Epic ability.